# I Want To Make A Super Simple Android App, But

Tags: android-studio, building, target-sdk

I just want to make a really basic android app - I'm wanting to rewrite this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.backyardapps.canadianincometaxcalculator

I wrote the app, originally, in Eclipse, under SDK 9. I now want to rewrite the app, with a few updated features but still want to keep to the same simplicity in design and functionality.

My challenge is that Android Studio keeps compiling with a higher SDK than what I want, so I get the Title bar showing up (with the settings menu button) across the top on my Lollipop device. I tried changing my build.gradle Module file to a minimum and target SDK of 10, but when I do that, all of the XML relating to themes produces errors (about 189 in total).

How can I setup my Android Studio so that it uses SDK 10 as the default sdk, so I can support the maximum number of devices, and have the most consistent user experience across devices/generations? (or CAN I even do so?)

Thanks in advance, guys!

Comment: if you dont want the actionbar/toolbar then you can simply specify that in your styles.xml :D

Comment: I tried doing that, but I can't figure out how because the actionbar doesn't appear to be in the styles.xml file. And that's what really gets me - because it only shows up on API 22 for some reason...

Comment: I managed to at least get the actionbar to go away by playing with the styles.xml, and found out I have to explicitly say "[theme].Light.NoActionBar" in order to get it to disappear.

I'm just hoping that, with a minimum SDK set to 10, I should have no problems running the app on all the desired devices, and will get a consistent experience..... *crosses fingers*

Thanks for your help, guys

Answer (score 0):

You can go down to you sdk manager and download your sdk you want to develop for then change the minimum sdk in your build.gradle.[image]

Comment: I've already tried that. The issue becomes that I want to set my TargetSDK to 10 but, when I make that change in gradle, I get a whole bunch of xml errors - primarily ones related to theme elements that cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the target SDK when you create a project when it says Minimum SDK but you have to download it first

Comment: I do have the SDK for APIs 10-22 installed. It seems the problem comes when I try to build for TargetSDK 10.

Comment: try to create a new project and in the second window, the "Target Android Devices" one, and set the minimum SDK to whatever you want, API 8 is fine because on every devices, it also shows you the percentage of Android devices that can run your app

Comment: Already done. I have no problems setting API 10 as the minimum API. My problem comes in trying to set it as the TARGET API.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the SDK version in your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Add something like this just below the opening

```
<uses-
   android:minSdkVersion="10"
   android:targetSdkVersion="10"  />
```

You can put the minimum threshold as low as you want as long as you have the right build tools installed in Android Studio.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. And changing the AndroidManifest.xml file seems to have no change on the overall outcome - the app still builds with the actionbar at the top (a result I can't seem to change). And if I try changing the TargetSDK in the build.gradle file, I get 189 errors relating to XML theme elements.